# Изменить значение тега в структуре во время исполнения

Tags: xml, golang, рефлексия, struct, runtime

Каким образом возможно в runtime поменять значение тега в структуре? К примеру,
есть такая структура:

```golang
type P struct {
    ID `xml:"ID"`
}
```

Нужно заменить: `` ID `xml:"ID"` `` на `` ID `xml:"UID"` ``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем случае это невозможно. Теги связываются с полями структур во время компиляции. Вы разве что можете навелосипедить во время исполнения копию структуры через ужасающие костыли отражения.

В вашем случае, вам легче воспользоваться `xml.Name` или интерфейсами: `xml.Marshaler` или `xml.Unmarshaler`. [Примеры](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#example__textMarshalXML) есть в документации пакета.

Вот пример для вас:

```golang
type T struct {
    ID   ID
    Text string
}

type ID struct {
    XMLName xml.Name
    ID      int `xml:",chardata"`
}

// …

// Для "ID":
v = T{ID: ID{XMLName: xml.Name{Space: "", Local: "ID"}, ID: 42}, Text: "ID"}

// Для "UID":
v = T{ID: ID{XMLName: xml.Name{Space: "", Local: "UID"}, ID: 42}, Text: "UID"}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/Y5VXpA3psLh.